# How to decode html formatted data in Datatables Server-Side Processing

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, datatables

I have a question table, which has HTML encoded records by the TinyMCE editor. The table has almost 5 thousand records. I am trying to list all records in DataTables using server-side functionality. 
While fetching HTML encoded data it outputs only  ?????? (encoded data is multilingual). charset=utf-8' is defined.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is sufficient information in your question to diagnose the `???` text. There are various places where you may be losing your UTF-8 encoding. It could even be as simple as the font you are using - does it actually support the range of characters you are trying to display? But there are other possiblities, too.

Comment: Side note: Your code (which you should include as formatted text in the question, not as a screenshot, please) has content type set to `application/json` followed by content type set to `text\html`. And a comment which says it needs to be JSON. That looks suspicious, regardless of the `???` issue.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Check out iconv. You can convert between character encodings.

Comment: Without Server-side processing, it works perfectly with data tables.

Comment: What do you mean server-side processing?

Comment: I know. I was curious about your modifications to the strings.

Comment: Already tried html_entity_decode(), but no help. I think something happens wrong while it processed through the JSON

Comment: Why do you encode with JSON? You're using a SQL db.

Comment: is there any other method to serialize columns data without JSON to fetch?

Comment: Lol..(-:  Let it go! Thanks for the help